# Meaning of "differentiable model of the environment dynamics" in RL

Tags: reinforcement-learning

Does anyone know what the term "differentiable model of the environment dynamics" means exactly?
I read the paper [Multi-Agent Actor-Critic for Mixed Cooperative-Competitive Environments](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.02275.pdf) where it is stated for example on page 4: "we do not assume a differentiable model of the environment dynamics, unlike in [[24]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.04908.pdf) ...".
Even after reading [24] it is not clear to me.
Does it mean that the information about the environment (which is incorporated in the state $\mathcal{S}$) changes with the agents actions $\mathcal{A}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dynamics of an environment describes how the state changes when you take an action. In the context of the deterministic environment in [24], a dynamics model would learn a mapping $\hat s' = f(s,a)$ which predicts the next state $s'$ resulting from taking the action $a$ in state $s$. A differentiable model simply means that this mapping is differentiable.

Also, in [24] they didn't actually use a differentiable model, they had direct access to the dynamics of the environment itself, and the dynamics of the environment were differentiable!

Comment: Just one minor question: differentiable in what? in "$s$", "$a$", or "$s,a$"?

Comment: both $s$ and $a$